# vagrant-proxyconf failing on setting proxy for docker

Tags: proxy, vagrant

I'm using vagrant with vagrant-proxyconf to configure the proxy for the vagrant box.
Unfortunately on vagrant up it fails and stops upon the Step "Configuring proxy for Docker..."

The error message is `` C:/Users/me/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-proxyconf-2.0.0/lib/vagrant-proxyconf/action/configure_docker_proxy.rb:50:in `write': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/vagrant-proxyconf-docker-config.json (Errno::ENOENT) ``

Any idea how I could solve this? It's happening on a freshly installed Win10 laptop, so Vagrant and VirtualBox is currently the newest version.

For completeness here the outputs until the failure:

```
==> csbox: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> csbox: Booting VM...
==> csbox: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
csbox: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
csbox: SSH username: vagrant
csbox: SSH auth method: private key
==> csbox: Machine booted and ready!
==> csbox: Configuring proxy for Apt...
==> csbox: Configuring proxy for Docker...
C:/Users/me/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-proxyconf-2.0.0/lib/vagrant-proxyconf/action/configure_docker_proxy.rb:50:in `write': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/vagrant-proxyconf-docker-config.json (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Comment: Uninstalling the plugin solved the problem in my case. After having uninstalled, the error was gone, and proxy was still working. Not sure what to make of that. 
My plan was actually: 

 - uninstall plugin
 - see if vagrant up would work then
 - install plugin
 - try again

Comment: you need to install older version of the plugin as advised here: https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf/issues/187